# FOSS State Diagram Program

Tags: diagram, uml

I am looking for a program to build state diagrams/machines in, the simpler the program the better.
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to just draw pictures,take a look at [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/), [Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/) or [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/). If you also want to do things like code generation, look closer into [this](http://modeling-languages.com/uml-tools/#open) comprehensive list.

Answer (score 0):

QM (http://www.state-machine.com/qm) is a simple, **free**, cross-platform, graphical UML modeling tool for designing and implementing real-time embedded applications based on state machines. QM supports nested states, entry/exit actions, actions on transitions, internal transitions, and choice segments. The generated C or C++ code is human readable. QM allows you to mix your own code with the synthesized code and use the tool to generate as much or as little of the overall code as you see fit.